# Distorted pixels rendered in WebView on Android + Cordova 3.3 + KendoMobile/SenchaTouch

Tags: android, cordova, webview, sencha-touch-2, kendo-mobile

we have problems on some devices running Android 4.1 with distorted or sheared rendering

Hybrid application is composed as Cordova 3.3 container and ExtJS Touch or Kendo Mobile application.
There's pixel grade distortion on some application screens. It seems but not proven that it happens on screens with scrollable portions, but distortion appears whenever scroller is active or not.

See pictures below.

If attention is payed to symptoms it seems that distortion appears as classic division problem - eg. if physical width is 399px and algorithm computes with 400px width, this causes the same distortion when drawing lines - I just want to point to similar symptom.

Environments we tested:

- cordova 2.9, 3.3
- Android 4.1, 4.3 (on 4.3 the problem does not
  appear)
- Sencha Touch 2.2, Kendo Mobile 2.3

Project parameters:

- cordova 3.3
- Android 4.1.2, API level 16
- hardware acceleration on
- `<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Any help is appreciated, since the problem is long-lasting and occurs on some Motorola devices as far as on some Hyuawei Ascend devices so it seems it can occur on any other devices.

Thanks

[image: distortion in KendoMobile application]

[image: distortion in ExtJS Touch application]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

At least when using KendoMobile.
The problems comes from scrolled views, especially from javascript scrollers, whose are commonly used in components like KendoMobile and so. 
Software scrollers are by default added to solve compatibility issues on lower versions of Android (2.x).
First of all, when you inspect generated HTML in desktop version, one can see that scroller div is added and scrolling by 3D translation is performed (translate3D). 
This very probably causes very slow performance of scrolling, weird behaviour when trying to call ScrollIntoView and generally (sad but true), it's crappy.
**If you can avoid that, do it.**

In KendoMobile everything can be solved by magic application setting useNativeScrolling.

```
window.kapp = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), 
{ transition: "fade", skin: "flat", useNativeScrolling: true});
```

Then, no software scrollers are used and it affects whole application.
Some accomodations in views must be done, but it's easy and one can then use divs with overflow:scroll;

Next time I will try to research SenchaTouch, if there's some translate3D (it seems Sencha uses it too).

One can read Kendo explanation http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/mobile/native-scrolling

Comment: BEWARE: Using  data-use-native-scrolling="true" acts differently than if using Application level useNativeScrolling. Also I used the following if (!kendo.support.mobileOS) kendo.support.hasNativeScrolling = true; to make scrollbars and scrollwheels and scrolltop-resetting work correctly on Desktop Chrome (and probably fixes other bugs too).

Comment: useNativeScrolling caused problems for this person too: "Instead of new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { useNativeScrolling: true }); which completely screwed our whole app, we used data-use-native-scrolling="true" for the views." in http://www.telerik.com/forums/native-vs-emulated-scrolling